# Search specific format in specific order for a text file data

Tags: python, parsing

I have a huge text file with below format (as an ASCII file). I am using python for processing the same. For this kind of files, I have few questions (in more generic way).

1. How do I check the correctness of the data format? Is there a way to specify a template and then verify the correctness for such text files? (similar to a dtd file of an xml).
2. Second question is parsing such file and reading data from the file. Like I expect `XYZ` data to come after the `time` row and would need to parse them. Any simple mechanism for such scenarios? Again like a template and parse mechanism.

```
===========================BEGIN=========================================  
2012-12-05  12:03  
XYZ 123(0)  654(2)  232(4)  
MON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  
POR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  
=========================== END =========================================  
===========================BEGIN=========================================  
2012-12-05  12:04  
XYZ 123(0)  654(2)  232(4)  
MON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  
POR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  
=========================== END =========================================  
===========================BEGIN=========================================  
2012-12-05  12:05  
XYZ 523(0)  654(2)  235(4)  
MON  83(0)   54(2)   32(4)  
POR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  
=========================== END =========================================  
===========================BEGIN=========================================  
2012-12-05  12:03  
XYZ 193(0)  644(2)  232(4)  
MON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  
POR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  
=========================== END =========================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a variation of the following :-

```
import re
s = '''===========================BEGIN=========================================  
2012-12-05  12:03  
XYZ 123(0)  654(2)  232(4)  
MON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  
POR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  
=========================== END =========================================  
===========================BEGIN=========================================  
2012-12-05  12:04  
XYZ 123(0)  654(2)  232(4)  
MON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  
POR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  
=========================== END =========================================  
===========================BEGIN=========================================  
2012-12-05  12:05  
XYZ 523(0)  654(2)  235(4)  
MON  83(0)   54(2)   32(4)  
POR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  
=========================== END =========================================  
===========================BEGIN=========================================  
2012-12-05  12:03  
XYZ 193(0)  644(2)  232(4)  
MON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  
POR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  
=========================== END =========================================
'''
print re.findall(r'=+BEGIN=+\s+(\d+-\d+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+)\s+(((XYZ|MON|POR).*\s+){3})', s)
```

This prints :-

```
[('2012-12-05  12:03', 'XYZ 123(0)  654(2)  232(4)  \nMON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  \nPOR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  \n'), 
 ('2012-12-05  12:04', 'XYZ 123(0)  654(2) 232(4)  \nMON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  \nPOR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  \n'), 
 ('2012-12-05  12:05', 'XYZ 523(0)  654(2)  235(4)  \nMON  83(0)   54(2)   32(4)  \nPOR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  \n'), 
 ('2012-12-05  12:03', 'XYZ 193(0)  644(2)  232(4)  \nMON  23(0)   54(2)   32(4)  \nPOR  13(0)   64(1)   92(2)  \n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

To address your first question - you could split each line of the file by tabs (if it is tab separated of course).  You then know which elements are in which positions of the list. 
So you could then use, for example dateutil.parser to detect if the date is a proper date string.

As for your second question - I would use a dictionary if possible. So, if XYZ is always the first entry on a line, I would use that value as the key.  The rest of the XYZ line could then be the data.
  Using this method, you are not bound to expecting the lines of the file to be in any particular order.